# How to select all fields from a table which are NOT NULL (NOT EMPTY)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select all fields that are not null without having to list all of them and check if each one is not null?

Is there a way to check if all the fields are not null and the select them by using something like "table.*" or something like that?

The other way for me is to select all and when list them with php, to check the value, but I want to do it with with sql. Any ideas how?

Comment: [We don't use HTML in posts here.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  We'd be able to better assist you if you gave us specific examples of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Or, more simply, ... `WHERE column IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

e.g. use `WHERE column NOT IN (SELECT column FROM table2)`

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't read the question properly. Check a row column for a NULL value with `WHERE column IS NOT NULL / IS NULL`

Answer (score -3):

You could try using WHERE * IS NOT NULL